# Writing a JSON file from dictionary, correcting the output

Tags: python, json, jsonpickle

So I am working on a conversion file that is taking a dictionary and converting it to a JSON file. Current code looks like:

```
data = {json_object}
json_string = jsonpickle.encode(data)
with open('/Users/machd/Mac/Documents/VISUAL CODE/CSV_to_JSON/JSON FILES/test.json', 'w') as outfile:
     json.dump(json_string, outfile)
```

But when I go to open that rendered file, it is adding three \ on the front and back of each string.

ps: sorry if I am using the wrong terminology, I am still new to python and don't know the vocabulary that well yet.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
import json
data = {"k": "v"}
with open( 'path_to_file.json', 'w') as f:
   json.dump(data, f)
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use `jsonpickle` to encode `dict` data.
The `json.dump` is a wrapper function that convert data to json format firstly, then write these string data to your file.

The reason why you found `\\` exist between each string is that, `jsonpickle` have took your data to string, after which the quote(") would convert to `Escape` character when `json.dump` interact.

Just use the following code to write `dict` data to json

```py
with open('/Users/machd/Mac/Documents/VISUAL CODE/CSV_to_JSON/JSON FILES/test.json', 'w') as outfile:
     json.dump(data, outfile)
```